# Как сделать выборку из базы данных для каждого одного значения по максимальной дате для каждого дня?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, group-by, dbeaver

Имею таблицу такого типа:

| name | status | changed_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | online | 2023-09-14 09:00 |
| A | offline | 2023-09-14 10:00 |
| A | online | 2023-09-14 10:15 |
| A | lunch | 2023-09-14 13:00 |
| A | online | 2023-09-14 14:00 |
| A | offline | 2023-09-14 21:15 |
| A | online | 2023-09-15 09:10 |
| A | lunch | 2023-09-15 13:00 |
| A | online | 2023-09-15 14:00 |
| A | offline | 2023-09-15 21:00 |
| B | online | 2023-09-14 09:04 |
| B | lunch | 2023-09-14 13:00 |
| B | online | 2023-09-14 14:00 |
| B | offline | 2023-09-14 21:04 |
| B | online | 2023-09-15 10:07 |
| B | lunch | 2023-09-15 13:00 |
| B | online | 2023-09-15 14:00 |
| B | offline | 2023-09-15 21:00 |

У меня 2 сотрудника A и B, они каждый день приходят на работу и меняют статус системы.
Я хочу получить данные для каждого сотрудника с максимальной датой статусов Online и Offline на каждой день. Т.е понять время прихода на работу и время ухода для каждого дня.
Хочу получить такую такую таблицу:

| name | status | changed_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | online | 2023-09-14 09:00 |
| A | offline | 2023-09-14 21:15 |
| A | online | 2023-09-15 09:10 |
| A | offline | 2023-09-15 21:00 |
| B | online | 2023-09-14 09:04 |
| B | offline | 2023-09-14 21:04 |
| B | online | 2023-09-15 10:07 |
| B | offline | 2023-09-15 21:00 |

Comment: ожидаемый результат немного не соответствует исходным данным. Обратите внимание на `changed_date`

Comment: да поменяла даты во 2ой таблице и забыла про 1ую. уже все одинаково

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       status,
       CASE status WHEN 'online'  THEN MIN(changed_date)
                   WHEN 'offline' THEN MAX(changed_date)
                   END AS changed_date
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1, 2, DATE_TRUNC('day', changed_date)
```

Comment: what is this used for?  DATE_TRUNC('day', changed_date)

Comment: to group daily?

Comment: Да, отрезаем время и группируем только по дате. А чё на импортном-то?

Comment: ахаха забыла что сайт русский, подумала иностранец, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

мы можем использовать многоуровневый CTE для реализации данного запроса, метод замороченный, но довольно образовательный.

Представим что вашу исходную таблицу зовут `Employee_logs`

```
WITH StatusChange AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        status,
        changed_date,
        LEAD(changed_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY changed_date) AS next_change_date
    FROM Employee_logs
),
OnlineOfflinePairs AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        MIN(changed_date) AS online_time,
        MAX(next_change_date) AS offline_time
    FROM StatusChange
    WHERE status = 'online'
    GROUP BY name, TO_CHAR(changed_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
)
SELECT
    oop.name,
    'online' AS status,
    oop.online_time AS changed_date
FROM OnlineOfflinePairs oop
UNION ALL
SELECT
    oop.name,
    'offline' AS status,
    oop.offline_time AS changed_date
FROM OnlineOfflinePairs oop
ORDER BY name, changed_date;
```

Comment: Чё так сложно-то?

Comment: @Akina flex....